# Chef Knife vault not decrypting correctly

Tags: chef-infra, knife

I'm creating vault secrets with chef:

```
knife vault create root data --json data_bags/root/data.json --search   'role:web' --admin admin --mode client
```

In order to read the `data bag item`,this is what I do:

```
knife data bag show root data --secret-file .chef/admin.pem
```

However I get this error:

```
ERROR: Chef::EncryptedDataBagItem::DecryptionFailure: Error decrypting   data bag value: 'bad decrypt'. Most likely the provided key is incorrect
```

How could this be, since chef-vault should be appending .chef/admin.pem in the first place.

Is there something missing here?

Comment: Encrypted data bags are different from those created by chef-vault. They don't use the shared secret, but the PKI instead.

Comment: Use "knife vault show" instead. As Stephen points out vaults use a different encryption algorithim

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it was suggested in the comment above, you should use the following command to read the vault:

```
knife vault show root data
```

The common-styled `knife data bag show` command doesn't work anymore because the vault is encrypted with so called "shared secret", which is not your client key.

Details: https://github.com/chef/chef-vault/blob/master/THEORY.md#data-bag-structure